# Can't register a View and ViewModel between 2 assemblies (UWP, Splat)

Tags: c#, reactiveui, splat, .net-standard-2.0

Using the latest RxUI v8 preview and Splat 2.0, in a UWP project referencing a .Net Standard 2.0 library, I can't register my view and viewmodel unless they reside in the same assembly.

I have:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterLazySingleton(() => new HomeView(), typeof(IViewFor<HomeViewModel>));
```

But Splat gives an error:

```
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to find type named 'RxUI.UWP.Core.Views.HomeView, RxUI.UWP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to resolve service for type 'ReactiveUI.IViewFor`1[[RxUI.UWP.Core.ViewModels.HomeViewModel, RxUI.UWP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to find type named 'ReactiveUI.IRoutableView, ReactiveUI, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to resolve service for type 'ReactiveUI.IViewFor`1[[ReactiveUI.IRoutableViewModel, ReactiveUI, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to resolve view for view model type 'ReactiveUI.IRoutableViewModel'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to find type named 'RxUI.UWP.Core.Views.HomeView, RxUI.UWP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

So it's looking for the HomeView in the "Core" assembly, but it resides in the UWP project. Here's the structure...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue with a similar environment as your. [The issue resided in the DefaultViewLocator](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/develop/src/ReactiveUI/ViewLocator.cs), since the view type is being renamed and resolved incorrectly to the viewmodel's assembly and namespace.
See lines 133-134 for how the view type name is determined:

```
var viewModelTypeName = viewModelType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
var proposedViewTypeName = this.ViewModelToViewFunc(viewModelTypeName);
```

Note: ViewModelToViewFunc is only a String.Replace that replaces "ViewModel" to "View" (see constructor).

To resolve this issue, my workaround was to create my own IViewLocator implementation, something like:

```
public class MyViewLocator : IViewLocator {
   public MyViewModelLocator(Assembly viewAssembly, string viewNameSpace)
...
   private IViewFor AttemptViewResolutionFor(Type viewModelType, string contract)
    {
        // proposed view type is now based on provided namespace + classname as modified by ViewModelToViewFunc
        if (viewModelType == null) return null;
        var viewModelTypeName = viewModelType.Name;
        var proposedViewTypeName = _viewNamespace + "." +  this.ViewModelToViewFunc(viewModelTypeName);
...

   private IViewFor AttemptViewResolution(string viewTypeName, string contract)
    {
        try
        {
            // resolve view type in the assembly of the view, and not assembly of the viewmodel
            var viewType = _viewAssembly.GetType(viewTypeName); // instead of Reflection.ReallyFindType(viewTypeName, throwOnFailure: false);
...
}
```

Finally, your custom viewlocator implementaiton must be registered with splat so that it overwrites DefaultViewLocator implementation:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant<IViewLocator>(new MyViewLocator(typeof(SplashView).Namespace, typeof(SplashView).Assembly));
```

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised this bug still exists in the latest version. To thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Btw, did you reuse the existing Splat code and change the parts above or a complete rewrite of this section?

Comment: I reused the existing code and only changed the parts above.